# code sign error while installing application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation, profile, provisioning, sign

I have registered for Apple Developer Program. I have installed my provisioning profile and other certificates successfully. But still, I am getting error while installing the app for ad-hoc distribution.

I am not sure about this, but I am getting my company name as "CXXXXXXXXX.abc-xyz.com" in mobileProvision certificate. Although I have entered my company name as "abcxyz" in developer profile.

Now, in info.plist, I have tried many options like com.abc-xyz.*, com.com.abc-xyz.*, com.abc-xyz.com.* but none of them works.

Here's the error that I am getting while installing:

Provisioning profile specifies the Application Identifier 'abc-xyz.com' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.abc-xyz.ApplicationName'

As far as I know, I think the problem may be in my company name as it contains '-', '.' and 'com'. But I have never entered name like abc-xyz.com anywhere apart from my email address. i.e. xxx@abc-xyz.com

I don't know if I am missing something. Is there any solution for this? Plz help if you have any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The bundle identifier in your info.plist should match the App ID of the provisioning profile. If your provisioning profile has an App ID of "CXXXXXXXXX.abc-xyz.com" then it will only sign apps with a bundle identifier of "abc-xyz.com", not "com.abc-xyz.ApplicationName".

You need to make the provisioning profile's App ID and the bundle identifier match. One way to do this is to set the App ID in the provisioning profile to "CXXXXXXXXX.com.abc-xyz.ApplicationName".

You can make the provisioning profile work for any app for your company by using a wildcard. "CXXXXXXXXX.com.abc-xyz.*" will match any bundle identifier that starts with "com.abc-xyz.".

For simplicity, I tend to wildcard the whole string ("CXXXXXXXXX.*") for Ad Hoc and Development profiles.

Comment: Hi Will,
Thanx for your answer. Now I understand that I have to make the provisioning profile's App ID and the bundle identifier match. But I don't know how do I change provisioning profile's App id.

Every time I create a mobileprovision, it takes "CXXXXXXX.abc-xyz.com" automatically. I want to make is simple like "CXXXXXX.abcxyz.*" or something like that. Can you suggest me how can I change that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I lost 1 hour messing around with the Code Signing Identity in my Project configurations with no luck. After I made the same changes to the Target everything worked.